# How to stop once QR code is scanned?

Tags: android, qr-code

I am using the `com.google.android.gms.vision` dependency to scan a QR-code.
The problem I am facing is that it keeps scanning the QR-code again and again. I want it to scan only once.

Here is my code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final SurfaceView cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
    final TextView barcodeInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.code_info);


    barcodeDetector =
            new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                    .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
                    .build();

    cameraSource = new CameraSource
            .Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 640)
            .build();

    cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
            } catch (IOException ie) {
                Log.e("CAMERA SOURCE", ie.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

            cameraSource.stop();
        }
    });

    barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
        @Override
        public void release() {

        }

        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();

            if (barcodes.size() != 0) {
                barcodeInfo.post(new Runnable() {    // Use the post method of the TextView
                    public void run() {
                        barcodeInfo.setText(    // Update the TextView
                                barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue
                        );
                         QRData = barcodeInfo.getText().toString().trim();
                        Log.d("TAG", barcodeInfo.getText().toString().trim());


                    }
                });
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm currently using [ZXing](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) for qr related stuff, it has a much easier and straightforward approach in to scanning and parsing the result. If you could still change what you're using right now, I suggest looking into it :)

Answer (score 1):

Just set result and call finish when your scan is completed in that activity. After that you need to catch result in parent activity (onActivityResult).

PS. You need to start QRScanner activity with startActivityForResult.

Edit: If QRScan is the same activity stop camera. And maybe you need to hide that surface.

Cheers :)